# How can I use .strip() to remove a newline in python?

Tags: python

I have used the methods shown in answers to similar questions to no avail. I am creating a program that asks the user for a username and then creates a file with the filename being the username entered, then asks the user for a password and then writes the entered password into the file. I also want the password to end in a newline as the password is not the only data I want to save in the file.

Then it will ask the user again for a username and open a file with that name, then ask the user for a password again and print "HUZZAH!" if the password entered and the password in the file match.

The following code **without the newline** works:

```
userinput = input("Username: ")
userinput += ".txt"
file = open(userinput, "w")
passchoice = input("Password: ")
file.write(passchoice)
print("")
userinput = input("Username: ")
userinput += ".txt"
file = open(userinput, "r")
password = file.readline()
file.close()
passinput = input("Password: ")
if(password == passinput):
    print("HUZZAH!")
```

It prints HUZZAH! and everything is wonderful. The problem occurs when I want to add the newline, as seen in the code below:

```
userinput = input("Username: ")
userinput += ".txt"
file = open(userinput, "w")
passchoice = input("Password: ")
file.write(passchoice)
file.write("/n") #Note the addition of the newline
print("")
userinput = input("Username: ")
userinput += ".txt"
file = open(userinput, "r")
password = file.readline()
file.close()
password = password.strip("") #stripping whitespace as instructed
passinput = input("Password: ")
if(password == passinput):
    print("HUZZAH!")
```

Nothing is printed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `"/n"` is not a newline. Did you mean `"\n"` perhaps?

Comment: Also, you'd have to use `password.strip()` (no first argument!). You are stripping with an *empty string*, meaning nothing is stripped.

Comment: `password.strip("")` is not the same as `password.strip()`

Comment: See the documentation for [`str.strip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip).

Answer (score -1):

According [tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_strip.htm) use:

```
str.strip([chars])
```

For example:

```
password.strip('\n')
```